# How do you view Ignored files in AccuRev?

Tags: accurev

Is there some way to view files in the AccuRev Client (v5.7) that have been ignored?

For some reason or other, some code files that do not follow the pattern in the .acignore file or the ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS env variable get ignored.  These are java files in directories with other java files, so there is no way that it could match the ignore restrictions.  But that is another problem.

So if I want to see which files in a local accurev workspace are ignored across all directories, is that possible?

(Note:  The Tools-Preferences-General tab menu item of "Show External Objects" - "Include Ignored Objects" shows ignored items - if you know what directory they're in)

Any help is appreciated.  This has happened several times, and I'm losing code.

(pining for my old svn days)

---

### edited

I can see the ignored files, if I know that they are there.  So I can drill down to the specific directory and see them listed in the workspace explorer results.  But if you have many, many directories ... you shouldn't have to manually look into each directory to see if there are ignored files.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need to set this preference (but you already know that):

The Tools-Preferences-General tab menu item of "Show External Objects" - "Include Ignored Objects" shows ignored items - if you know what directory they're in

Can you post the contents of your .acignore file and ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS env variable?

Also, include the output from the command 'accurev stat '?

Maybe we can solve your problem.

Comment: Updated my question with additional details

Answer (score 0):

As Jason mentioned, the status of the individual files may help to explain what's going on. If you see "missing", then the files are not present on disk. Also check your include/exclude rules. Files that have been excluded won't be present on disk or seen in the AccuRev workspace explorer.